# Solr faceted search building widgets

Tags: solr

We want to build a faceted search within our application. For example, if we have quantity field whose values range from 1-20 for 2000 records. We need to allow the user to filter by those values.
To, accomplish this we are planning to extract the quantity field sort, eliminate duplicate records and build a widget on the left hand side of the screen, so the user can select what we need.

Is there a way to get this faceted criteria from Solr or any better way to implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what Solr calls a Facet, and is enabled using [`facet=true`](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#facet)

```
&facet=true&facet.field=quantity
```

.. will give you a facet entry back in the response, containing a count for each unique value in the `quantity` field. When the user clicks a quantity link, apply a `fq` for that particular quantity value, such as `fq=quantity:4`.

You can use `facet.sort` to determine if the facet should be sorted by hits (most popular quantity first) or alphabetical.

[Multi-Select Facets and Local Params](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#Multi-Select_Faceting_and_LocalParams) might also be useful, if you want to still show the original counts while allowing the user to drill down into the selection when applying an `fq` with the selected quantity as a criteria.